# Can not make the search bar and the results appear on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, frontend

I am making a website. It requires two drop-downs and one search field. Depending on the value user provides, PHP will show the search result just below of that in one page. But the search bar and results have a lot of distance between them.

Here is my front:

[image: Here is the search bar taking the whole place]

[image: Here is the search result bellow the search bar]

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HealthY-Admin-Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="appointment_dummy.css">
    <!-- Add other necessary stylesheets or scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="frame">
        <nav>
            <a href="homepage.php"><img src="images\healthylight.png" class="logo" id="logo"></a>
            <div class="sidepanel">
                <a class="signup"><?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?></a>
                <a href="logout.php" class="btn">Log out</a>
                <img src="images\sun.png" id="icono"/>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <form id="filterForm" action="appointment_process.php" method="post">
            <div class="content">
                <main class="table">
                    <section class="filters">
                        <!-- First Dropdown -->
                        <select id="filter1" name="select1">
                            <option value="dhaka">Option 1</option>
                            <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                            <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
                        </select>

                        <!-- Second Dropdown -->
                        <select id="filter2" name="select2">
                            <option value="medicine">Option A</option>
                            <option value="optionB">Option B</option>
                            <option value="optionC">Option C</option>
                        </select>

                        <!-- Search Input -->
                        <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="search-input" placeholder="Search...">

                        <!-- Button for search/filter action -->
                        <button type="submit" id="searchBtn">Search</button>
                    </section>
                </main>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="content">
            <main class="table">
                <section class="table__header">
                    <h1 class="">Available Doctors </h1>
                </section>
                <section class="table__body">
                    <table id="doctorTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Doctor Name</th>
                                <th>Speciality</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <!-- <th>Actions</th> -->
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                                // This part should be replaced with an AJAX call in a separate script
                                // You cannot use PHP directly inside JavaScript
                            ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </section>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#filterForm').on('submit', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission

                var formData = $(this).serialize(); // Serialize form data

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'appointment_process.php',
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        var tableBody = $('#doctorTable tbody');
                        tableBody.empty();

                        if (response && response.length > 0) {
                            $.each(response, function(index, doctor) {
                                var row = '<tr>' +
                                    '<td>' + doctor.Name + '</td>' +
                                    '<td>' + doctor.Speciality + '</td>' +
                                    '<td>' + doctor.Address + '</td>' +
                                    '</tr>';
                                tableBody.append(row);
                            });
                        } else {
                            tableBody.append('<tr><td colspan="3">No data found</td></tr>');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error(error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS content:

```
/* Example styling for dropdown options */
select option {
    background-color: #ffffff; /* Background color */
    color: #000000; /* Text color */
    padding: 8px 12px; /* Padding */
}

/* Hover effect on options */
select option:hover {
    background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Hover background color */
}
/* Existing CSS code... */

/* Button for search/filter action */
#searchBtn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--secondary-color);
    padding: 14px 40px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(0, 255, 187), rgb(0, 181, 133));
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px; /* Adjust margin as needed */
}

#searchBtn:hover {
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(244, 37, 1), rgb(184, 1, 1));
}

/* Adjust the styles above based on your design preferences */
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

:root {
    --primary-color: #ffffff;
    --secondary-color: #1b4063;
    --detail: rgb(1, 195, 142);
    --hover_animation: rgb(1, 195, 142);

    --back: url(images/Bg1.png);
    --transbg: rgba(28, 65, 99, 0.075);
    --trans-secondary-color:  rgba(28, 65, 99, 0.5);
    --trans-primary-color: rgba(28, 65, 99, 0.4);
}

.light-home {
    --primary-color: rgb(28, 65, 99);
    --secondary-color: #ffffff;
    --detail: rgb(1, 195, 142);
    --hover_animation: #1b4063;
    --back: url(images/Bg2.png);
    --transbg: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075);
    --trans-secondary-color: rgba(28, 65, 99, 0.098);
    --trans-primary-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.256);
}

.frame {
    /* display: flex; */
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: var(--back);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 10px 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
    width: 140px;
}

.logo:hover {
    width: 144px;
}

nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    right: 32%;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 15px;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--secondary-color);
    font-weight: 500;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: var(--hover_animation);
}

.sidepanel {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.signup {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--primary-color);
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;

}
.signup:hover {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: var(--hover_animation);
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--secondary-color);
    padding: 14px 40px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(0, 255, 187), rgb(0, 181, 133));
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}

.btn:hover {
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(244, 37, 1), rgb(184, 1, 1));
}

#icono {
    width: 25px;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#icono:hover {
    width: 30px;
}

.content {
    width: 90vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* background-color: aqua; */
}

main.table {
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 87vw;
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: var(--transbg);
    backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
    box-shadow: 0 0.4rem 0.8rem #0005;
    border-radius: 3rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border: 5px solid var(--detail);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    color: var(--primary-color);
}

th, td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table__header {
    color: var(--primary-color);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2.6rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 255, 187, 0.5), rgba(0, 181, 133, 0.5));
}

.table__body {
    /* display: flex; */
    width: 100%;
    max-height: calc(89%-0.8rem);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2.6rem;
    background-color: var(--trans-secondary-color);
    overflow: auto;
    /* justify-content: center; */
}

.table__body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 1rem;
    width: 1rem;
}


.table__body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    height: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 3rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 255, 187, 0.5), rgba(0, 181, 133, 0.5));
    visibility: hidden;
}

.table__body:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    visibility: visible;
}

thead th {
    padding: 2rem;
    position: sticky;
    font-size: 18px;
    top: 0;
    left: 9;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: var(--trans-primary-color);
}
tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: rgba(1, 195, 142, 0.4);
}

.accept_btn {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(1, 244, 33), rgb(1, 184, 13));
    opacity: 70%;
    border-top-left-radius: 2rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2rem;

}

.click_btn {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(244, 236, 1), rgb(220, 170, 6));
    border-top-left-radius: 2rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2rem;
    opacity: 70%;
}

.reject_btm {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(244, 37, 1), rgb(184, 1, 1));
    border-top-left-radius: 2rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2rem;
    opacity: 70%;
}

.accept_btn:hover {
    opacity: 100%;
    border-radius: 2rem;
}
.click_btn:hover {
    opacity: 100%;
    border-radius: 2rem;
}
.reject_btm:hover {
    opacity: 100%;
    border-radius: 2rem;
}

.tdb {
    padding: 3rem, 1rem;
}
```

How can I fix the problem?

I was expecting the drop downs and the search bar to take a normal space and the search result will be taking the places bellow. Just in which way it looks beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

```css
main.table{
  height: 90vh;
}
```

This is the cause of the problem.
Do this -

```css
form .table{
  padding: 30px auto !important; /* top & bottom 30px padding */
}
```